# C++ - Order of constructor initialization with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A1 {
public:
    A1() {
        std::cout << "A1, ";
    }
};

class A2 {
public:
    A2() {
        std::cout << "A2, ";
    }
};

class AA1 : virtual public A1, public A2 {
public:
    AA1() {
        std::cout << "AA1, ";
    }
};

class AA2 : public A1, virtual public A2 {
public:
    AA2() {
        std::cout << "AA2, ";
    }
};

class B : public AA1, virtual public AA2 {
public:
    B() {
        std::cout << "B, ";
    }
};


int main() {
    B ob1;

    return 0;
}
```

and the output of this program is

```
A1, A2, A1, AA2, A2, AA1, B,
```

and I don't quite understand why that is.

I see that the order should be the following:

> The very first constructors to be executed are the virtual base
>   classes anywhere in the hierarchy. They are executed in the order they
>   appear in a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the graph of base
>   classes, where left to right refer to the order of appearance of base
>   class names.

Knowing that, shouldn't class B first initialize class AA2, which would first initialize class A2? Why does the order start with A1?

Comment: Draw the inheritance graph, apply a depth-first left-to-right traversal, and you'll find this answer ;) `A1` is at the top of the hierarchy with `A2`, so both needs to be initialized first, and `A1` ends up left of `A2` in the hierarchy which is why it gets initiaklized first.

Comment: Perhaps the other important point is that you need ALL classes that inherit A1 to inherit it virtually for it to only have 1 instance

Comment: Virtual base classes, not virtual **direct** base classes. In your example, `A1` and `A2` are also virtual base classes of `B`.